# launch4j bundled jre error

Tags: launch4j

I am using launch4j for the first time and I get a compile error. I have copy the jre folder to folder "C:\Users\8xy2ms\Desktop\smsModel\smsModel".

Here is the error code:

```
Compiling resources
Generated resource file...
LANGUAGE 0, 1
1 RCDATA BEGIN ".\\jre6\0" END
18 RCDATA BEGIN "1\0" END
21 RCDATA BEGIN "http://java.com/download\0" END
20 RCDATA BEGIN "32\0" END
101 RCDATA BEGIN "An error occurred while starting the application.\0" END
102 RCDATA BEGIN "This application was configured to use a bundled Java Runtime Environment but the runtime is missing or corrupted.\0" END
103 RCDATA BEGIN "This application requires a Java Runtime Environment\0" END
104 RCDATA BEGIN "The registry refers to a nonexistent Java Runtime Environment installation or the runtime is corrupted.\0" END
17 RCDATA BEGIN "true\0" END
```

and here is the project xml

```
<launch4jConfig>
  <dontWrapJar>false</dontWrapJar> 
  <headerType>gui</headerType> 
  <jar>C:\Users\8xy2ms\Desktop\smsModel\smsModel\test2.jar</jar> 
  <outfile>C:\Users\8xy2ms\Desktop\smsModel\smsModel\test.exe</outfile> 
  <errTitle /> 
  <cmdLine /> 
  <chdir /> 
  <priority>normal</priority> 
  <downloadUrl>http://java.com/download</downloadUrl> 
  <supportUrl /> 
  <customProcName>false</customProcName> 
  <stayAlive>false</stayAlive> 
  <manifest /> 
  <icon /> 
  <jre>
  <path>./jre6</path> 
  <minVersion /> 
  <maxVersion /> 
  <jdkPreference>preferJre</jdkPreference> 
  </jre>
  </launch4jConfig>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using extra options in it. Cancel them all, and it will soon work out for you. Just go for the ones which are compulsory only.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question, but this happened to me today and Google led me here...

The problem for me was the path separator. Had to use '' instead of '/'. So the correct is: `<path>.\jre6</path>`